# Error importing nuke module in a python script and opening file

Tags: python, import, nuke

I am getting these errors and completely lost on what I am missing, if anything, to be installed or appended to my sys.path.  Does anyone know if this is a package that just needs to be installed that it is looking for?  I tried scouring the Python directory for PyOpenColorIO, but couldn't find it.

```
import sys
import os
import csv

sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files\Nuke9.0v8\lib\site-packages")

import nuke

nuke.scriptOpen(r'B:\NodeExpTest.nk')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/Program Files/Nuke9.0v8/plugins\nukescripts\ViewerProcess.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ocionuke
  File "C:/Program Files/Nuke9.0v8/plugins\ocionuke\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cdl
  File "C:/Program Files/Nuke9.0v8/plugins\ocionuke\cdl.py", line 7, in <module>
    import PyOpenColorIO as OCIO
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/Program Files/Nuke9.0v8/plugins\nukescripts\ViewerProcess.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ocionuke
  File "C:/Program Files/Nuke9.0v8/plugins\ocionuke\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cdl
  File "C:/Program Files/Nuke9.0v8/plugins\ocionuke\cdl.py", line 7, in <module>
    import PyOpenColorIO as OCIO
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/Program Files/Nuke9.0v8/plugins\nukescripts\ViewerProcess.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ocionuke
  File "C:/Program Files/Nuke9.0v8/plugins\ocionuke\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cdl
  File "C:/Program Files/Nuke9.0v8/plugins\ocionuke\cdl.py", line 7, in <module>
    import PyOpenColorIO as OCIO
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: It looks like Nuke is looking for the [PyOpenColorIO package](http://opencolorio.org/installation.html) that is not yet installed. Not sure where documentation is for building and installing on a windows machine, but some Googling seems to suggest installing on windows may be non-trivial and involve Cygwin, but nevertheless installing OpenColorIO should fix the error message.

Comment: Yes I figured it is some kind of module isn't installed, which confuses me since one would expect Nuke to handle it.  I am not sure that installing it is so trivial.  I did go to the website and there is no binary at all for windows that would make it simple... from the looks of it

Comment: One other question: Have you tried changing your current working directory to the Nuke installation root and running the Python interpreter that is distributed with Nuke?

Answer (score 1):

`PyOpenColorIO` definitely ships with Nuke. I believe your issue is by the `nuke` module not currently being able to locate all of Nuke's library dependencies properly. Many of the modules are stored in non-standard locations compared to a traditional Python installation (for example, the `pythonextensions` directory in the root of the Nuke installation.

In order for these libraries to be found, I believe you need to add the root directory of the Nuke installation and possibly the `pythonextensions` directory to the `PATH` environment variable (on Windows). I don't have Nuke installed on this machine, but I can confirm the appropriate locations the next time I'm on my work machine.